# ¿Cómo puedo generar código HTML desde el ASPX con base de datos MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, asp.net

Estoy trabajando una página en `ASP` con Visual Basic puesto que es un trabajo universitario y así me lo solicitan y me gustaría que me ayudaran con un pequeño problema al ver información de una `BD MySQL` (phpmyadmin). No he encontrado una respuesta óptima en Internet y estoy contra reloj.

El problema me surge cuando quiero mostrar la información, al crear la página luego de haber creado el diseño (barra de navegación, footer, sidebar etc) he dejado un `DIV` centrado el cual pensaba dejar para mostrar la información.

Este `DIV` lleva unas clases `bootstrap`  y un id para manipularlo desde el código:

```
<div runat ="server" id ="htmlcontenedor" class="col-md-9 scroll">
```

**P.D.**: scroll clase css para darle un overflow-y.

y quiero  ingresar nuevos "DIV" dentro, los cuales lleven la clase de `boostrap` para la GRID `col-md-3 o 4` para un mejor diseño y dentro de este `DIV` mostrar una imagen un "label" y un botón, si en la base de datos tengo 15 datos distintos (lo que debo mostrar son habitaciones de hoteles, serían 15 habitaciones con número e imagen distintas).

Desde el código he logrado agregar paneles dentro de este DIV, creando nuevos objetos dentro de un ciclo `FOR` el cual tiene el rango de un `COUNT` A la base de datos pero desde código no puedo manipular los fondo de estos paneles  ejemplo:

```
        Dim btn = New Button
        With btn
            btn.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Dotted
            btn.Text = "Hola"
        End With
        Dim img = New Image()
        With img
            img.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Dashed
        End With
        Dim panelsito = New Panel()
        With panelsito
            .BackColor = ???? (no eh logrado darle color) 
            .Height = 200
            .Width = 300
        End With
        panelsito.Controls.Add(btn)
        panelsito.Controls.Add(img)
        htmlcontenedor.Controls.Add(panelsito)
```

Prefiero generar código `HTML` para ingresar dentro del DIV contenedor un ejemplo de lo que me gustaría lograr:

```
<div clas="col-md-3" >
  <img src="">
  <label> (numero de hab en la BD o dato de la BD)</label>
  <button value='Reservar'>
</div>
```

y poder agregarlo al DIV en el HTML, algo como:

```
htmlcontenedor.control.add... y si es posible agregarlo..
```

**P.D**: Sé que no debo almacenar imágenes dentro de una `BD` pero estoy contra tiempo y no tengo servidor o algo es un laboratorio de última hora de la universidad y he optado por ingresar las a la `BD` temporalmente

Investigando en internet me he encontrado con

```
<% Response.Write("<div class='col-md-4 margen'> hola mundo </div>")%>
```

dentro de un ciclo por ejemplo lo hace, pero no tengo como agregar esto dentro del DIV

y también he visto como hacerlo de una forma más "directa" dentro del propio DIV en el código el cual sería por ejemplo:

```
<%--<% For i As Integer = 0 To 5 %>       <% Response.Write("<div 
class='col-md-4 margen'> hola mundo </div>")%>    <% Next%>--%>
```

y puedo generar todo dentro del DIV pero de esta manera no puedo hacer una consulta a la BD para traer los datos. Si tienen una forma de conectarme de esta manera a la `BD MySQL` y hacer la consulta para imprimir los datos directamente allí se los agradecería. Para realizar una consulta supongo para traer la cantidad con un "count" y luego hacer un ciclo aunque sea una manera bastante ineficiente, pero ya casi no me queda tiempo, disculpad la "pregunta tan larga" pero necesitaba explicar de la mejor manera que quería lograr. Gracias de antemano, un saludo y disculpad el texto.

Comment: La pregunta esta bien.. solo mira [tour] para que sepas como andamos, y si puedes chequea [ask] para futuras preguntas. mi unica duda es, si puedes crear todo por codigo, porque no pasas el color al panel como corresponde? cual es tu problema con eso? probaste con Color.Black (por ejemplo)

Comment: Hola! por supuesto lo intente pero al parecer no me reconocía eso, también intente con QBcolor y RGB color pero ninguna me permitía darle un color al panel, y con esos códigos podía pero me gustaba mas la opción de generar el html para aplicar bootstrap como la respuesta que dio el señor abajo, gracias por su tiempo igual muy amable.!

Comment: Perfecto!! la proxima vez, aclara que cosas probaste y cuales no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear controles genéricos html se utiliza la clase System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

A continuación te ilustro con un ejemplo:

```vb
'Número de la habitación
Dim habitacion As String = "habitacion102"

Dim div As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div")
div.ID = "div" & habitacion
'Inicio Ejemplos propiedades
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Yellow")
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red")
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "100px")
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "400px")
div.Style.Add("Padding", "10px")
'Ejemplo con class
div.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-3")

Dim img As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("img")
img.ID = "img" & habitacion
img.Attributes.Add("src", "https://y.cdrst.com/foto/hotel-sf/8a4d/galeriaresp/hotel-indigo-rome-st-george-habitacion-3c63c99.jpg")

Dim label As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("label")
label.ID = "label" & habitacion
label.InnerText = habitacion

Dim button As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("button")
button.ID = "btn" & habitacion
button.Attributes.Add("type", "button")
button.Attributes.Add("value", "Reservar")
button.InnerText = "Reservar"

div.Controls.Add(img)
div.Controls.Add(label)
div.Controls.Add(button)

htmlcontenedor.Controls.Add(div)
```

Este sería el html resultado:

[image: HTML resultado]

Comment: ohh que buena! la había visto investigando pero no la comprendí así que la ignore pero que buen ejemplo sencillo y fácil de entender muchas gracias, esto era justo lo que necesitaba, gracias por su tiempo muy amable